# Data getting corrupted over aes file transfer python tkinter

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, aes

I am working on a project where you can send a file over a socket and it is aes encrypted. And it works it encrypts the data and sends it over the socket and it decrypts it fine but the image is getting messed up below is the example of the before image and after how can I correct this?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

The encrypt and decrypt are in a separate module I created that is why they a referenced like they are below

Encryption and decryption code:

```
def encrypt(key, data, iv):
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return encryptor.encrypt(data)

def decrypt(key, data, iv):
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return decryptor.decrypt(data)
```

Server Code:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5000))
s.listen(1)
c, addr = self.s.accept

name = c.recv(1024)
name = name.split("/")[-1]

newFile = open(self.curpath + name, "wb")
stop = False

while True:
    data = c.recv(24*1024)

    print(data[-4:])
    if data[-4:] == "DONE":
        break

    data = decrypt(self.key, data, self.iv)
    newFile.write(data)

    print("STOP")
    newFile.close()
```

Client Code:

```
s. = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5000)

item = "Splash.png"
s.send(item)

with open(item, "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            chunk = fp.read(64*1024)

            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                chunk += " " * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
            s.send(encrypt(self.key, chunk, self.iv))

s.send("DONE")
print("Done")
```

Comment: The example code isn't runnable, because the code that creates the connections is missing.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Sorry about that I just updated it!

Comment: You are adding padding to the sent chunks to bring their size up to a multiple of 16, but you aren't *removing* that padding when the chunks are received - and couldn't possibly do so anyway, as there's no way to tell how much padding was added.

Comment: @jasonharper what would be a good way to go about the padding?

Comment: You could try `.rstrip(' ')` to remove right-side spaces. However it would be best to use PKCS7 padding. If you're using Pycryptodome you will find padding functions in `Crypto.Util.Padding`. If you're using Pycrypto you can copy Pycryptodome's padding functions. Just make sure to pad the last chunk regardless of its size, otherwise wou won't be able to unpad correctly.

Comment: @t.m.adam that worked good using rstrip() could you post that as a answer?

Comment: Glad it worked! Sorry, I'm a little busy at the moment, but you could answer your question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using @t.m.adam comment I was able to get the software to run correctly using `.rstrip(" ")`